# Maximal group of objects and attributes in a formal context

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I am reading a [paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271629/1-s2.0-S0164121219X00084/1-s2.0-S0164121219301311/am.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIDh1UYwkRJeT6J7UNe8EvZ8O%2BcjX5TSblv3%2Br3H9DsmzAiEA4ngQUFX05TurMoZKMU12ovcgtdXAeveQFvfolfjmxGAq1QQIuv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDH2sPztsRryiPLfeYCqpBBrNpcLHjzLVOCceOBMOBjXnFWlVrySJ6N9Qgv6gWTn3WrrDrxoKRo%2Fsp6AJUWtJ4P8%2BhQktWDczkG0z2X%2Br8tnxUhPAK8aKmITEWl9wWRIH%2FC8rwceywHtGeeDpU6It613Y77uTPiPFjmL1JPDwqjzCyB9QxuHXytBzjFHXE0TS93AkjSG0D52dS175U7dAreQXBA6oORx75pG%2FkI%2BhBWk%2BXDSsj4zrNp30GobDUqhYcu2RMLkCmixgb27hvwhqrd0wW7YwgiE%2B4ly3feGVKTiemWC1Tp9klfBjVLcAQJ5vghaFI72zLMpBYxcH%2FqLa5v16LmPzirfT9nk3RznyUHSZ7NR9uV%2FnhWxAOY%2BvvKy6AxJ9W%2Bq84u7dOVv0s7BMBfvfmPnE%2FqdpoKY9SL%2FcJGOjtjwf%2B%2B%2BszOscJLpA6SruA8HzWvd1gFMEBhCNGO7%2BNdu%2Fl7gzYaAI3aMyoZB0b%2BwuhFTxguG2lnWdMHAM9PmczJbxbM3es2bL1IyU2si6imzvnq6nvLcgVAwIeHpHawCOoZeLn%2F%2FYZ3RP3SmxhpP6OSYlBFOOsmYTsk11%2BwQwkGxiMAlMC%2FrReTZSnQTjiQb4jMCnD4Rk94NxD%2FYasSksHKS6IkT8neJPasqi59awSPqCwhlE8r2CNevQYxlrXKQbKRLTEJz4CsrngUf7x%2FV7i9kC4BhORnXulPnkhYcQfegWo%2BKUngPO3HU0G3jXwzE6u93QJgLXsfgw7J6GmQY6qQHEgCyiHOx2a0vEASnUI0WA6yvnhnqKrus52t%2BZ6%2BxALUQ%2FXV%2FqwBhvqKAH4Jll79NiZyFKUtwSrIGexT6fm6jtt095M7Y%2BUJxulVazEAtJY9%2F3Wjpi%2F%2FsQE1f%2BsrUrQ4yhwYjta%2FTXiYPGvzaB9RRqwUoJ9Q5OqtBSPNNkdq2X3M1SHQ9YsXi5HeOftlaPoq4K9wUctC%2BQ6ihy4rNyMPa8vJN8fEvDZkzQ&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220914T091549Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYRJOJJRGC%2F20220914%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=23c260c058d79ac879aba1b57ba55bb9130d0cbaed0b3386502e81f02f99c3d6&hash=a644a1ce0c32dbd1560b38490492070c14c571e7f7475c85471e08b0cf919fec&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0164121219301311&tid=pdf-633279d8-effa-41d6-8fcb-34012676a7b6&sid=3f3fa8c959cdc14c150b4d33b324fa145570gxrqb&type=client) that uses [formal concept analysis](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume24/cimiano05a-html/node3.html). Their formal context table is as follows:

[image]

They say:

> In light gray, we highlight the presence of a concept, composed of (1) an extent, which is a maximal group of objects `(v2, v3, v4 and v5)`, and of (2) an intent, which is the maximal group of attributes `(WebBrowser, Navigation and Spatial)` these objects share.

However, I seem to disagree with this. In my opinion, maximal group of objects should be `(v5, v6, v7, v8, v9)` and maximal group of attributes will become `(WebBrowser, Navigation, Tabbing, CustomizedTabbing)`.

Comment: But $v_1$ also has those same attributes, so it should be $$(\{v_1,v_5,v_6,v_7,v_8,v_9\},\{WebBrowser,Navigation,Tabbing,CustomizedTabbing\}),$$ right?

Comment: Also, maximal doesn't mean it has more elements, it means that it's not contained in a larger one, so the one in light grey is indeed maximal.

Comment: @amrsa indeed. `v1` also has those same attributes.

Comment: @amrsa "it means that it's not contained in a larger one", kindly help me understand this

Comment: So the concept $(\{v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5\},\{Webbrowser,Navigation,Spatial\})$ is maximal, since if you add some other object then you have to exclude some attribute, and if you add some other attribute, then you have to exclude some object

Comment: @amrsa can't same logic `({v1, v3, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9}, {WebBrowser, Navigation, Tabbing, CustomizedTabbing})` maximal?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, a set of objects $G$ is maximal wrt sharing the same set of attributes $M$ iff $(G,M)$ is a concept.